# Override Calibri font in uiwebview

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview

I'm writing a mail app that receives HTML format mail. Some of the messages contain online styles that reference the Calibri font.

I'd like to override the Calibri font (which maps to times new roman on iOS) with Helvetia. However other inline font styles should remain unchanged.

Is there any way to remap all instances of a font name to another font?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? The CSS here should override your inline font styles, respectively.

```
div[style] {
font-family: Helvetia !important;
}
```